# Send soap request to wsdl website

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, python-requests

How to get requests from a website? I found this:
http://www.yodaspeak.co.uk/webservice/yodatalk.php?wsdl

But I can figure out how to send a request to it and get a response.

So far I've tried with:

```
import requests


    yoda_params = {"inputText": 'Is this working?'}
    yoda_url = 'http://www.yodaspeak.co.uk/webservice/yodatalk.php?'
    yoda_re = requests.get(yoda_url, params=yoda_params)
    yoda_text = yoda_re.json()
    print(yoda_text)
```

But it didn't worked.

```
Name: yodaTalk
Binding: http://www.yodaspeak.co.uk/webservice/yodatalkBinding
Endpoint: http://www.yodaspeak.co.uk/webservice/yodatalk.php
SoapAction: uri:http://www.yodaspeak.co.uk/webservice/yodatalk#yodaTalk
Style: rpc
Input:
  use: literal
  namespace: uri:http://www.yodaspeak.co.uk/webservice/yodatalk
  encodingStyle:
  message: yodaTalkRequest
  parts:
    inputText: xsd:string
Output:
  use: literal
  namespace: uri:http://www.yodaspeak.co.uk/webservice/yodatalk
  encodingStyle:
  message: yodaTalkResponse
  parts:
    return: xsd:string
Namespace: uri:http://www.yodaspeak.co.uk/webservice/yodatalk
Transport: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http
Documentation: Pass any string and it will be returned as Yoda-Speak.
```

I also found this by mistake while trying to put InputText=Something in the url

Update:

I tried with zeep but when I run `python -mzeep 'http://www.yodaspeak.co.uk/webservice/yodatalk.php?wsdl` I get:

```
No namespace defined for 'http' ('http://www.yodaspeak.co.uk/webservice/yodatalkPortType')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using any soap library (for example, [zeep](http://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/)).
There's `wsdl` in `http://www.yodaspeak.co.uk/webservice/yodatalk.php?wsdl`, so it's about `soap` using, I suppose.

Comment: I tried but when I run  'python3 -mzeep 'http://yodaspeak.co.uk/webservice/yodatalk.php?wsdl' I 'get No namespace defined for 'http'

Comment: Thanks... using a soap library helped a lot. Unfortunately soap didn't worked at all so I had to search for another soap library [suds-jurko](https://pypi.org/project/suds-jurko/0.6/) an updated version of suds made by another author but it works on python 3.x